# How identify left (True) and right (False) branch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, pydot

I exported a scikit-learn DecisionTree to a .dot file with export_graphviz.

In a different module I want to load the tree from the .dot file and fill a different tree structure.

**Question:** How do I decide if a branch is the left one (take if condition is True) or the right one (taken if condition is False)? Is it just by order in the .dot file?

**Example:**

```
digraph Tree {
0 [label="condition 1\ngini = 0.16772448\nsamples = 5000", shape="box"] ;
1 [label="gini = 0.0000\nsamples = 2994\nvalue = [    0.  2994.]", shape="box"] ;
0 -> 1 ;
2 [label="gini = 0.0000\nsamples = 2994\nvalue = [    2006.  0.]", shape="box"] ;
0 -> 2 ;
[..]
```

So here 0->1 would be Left/True?

**Question:** How do I get this information from the pydot.Dot.obj_dict? Does the attribute `sequence` help?

**Example:**

```
pprint.pprint(dot_tree.obj_dict)
{'attributes': {},
'current_child_sequence': 18,
'edges': {('0', '1'): [{'attributes': {},
                        'parent_edge_list': None,
                        'parent_graph': <pydot.Dot object at 0x2778fd0>,
                        'points': ('0', '1'),
                        'sequence': 3,
                        'type': 'edge'}],
[..]
'name': 'Tree',
'nodes': {'0': [{'attributes': {'label': '"a condition\\ngini = 0.16772448\\nsamples = 5000"',
                             'shape': '"box"'},
                 'name': '0',
                 'parent_graph': <pydot.Dot object at 0x2778fd0>,
                 'parent_node_list': None,
                 'port': None,
                 'sequence': 1,
                 'type': 'node'}],
[..]
'parent_graph': <pydot.Dot object at 0x2778fd0>,
'simplify': False,
'strict': False,
'subgraphs': {},
'suppress_disconnected': False,
'type': 'digraph'}
```

Comment: If you get no results from here, I suggest [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/798f44265472ff4d954c0f78674bb64742408a76/sklearn/tree).